# The Database zzz is not accessible

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server instance which has several Database in it. I had to restart the server, after restart one of the databases would not launch and I click the + Icon besides it, it says

> The Database zzz is not accessible(ObjectExplorer).

No permission is changed, nothing is changed just I restart the Server.

[image]

[image]

I have sent the Log file, it says that

> Open failed ,Could not open file .....mdf

Both files exist on the disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot shows operation system error 5, which is Access Denied.

Check the permissions on the files to ensure the account the SQL Server service is running under has access.

See [How to troubleshoot Error 17204 and 17207 in SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2015754) (Microsoft Support)

That knowledge base article includes several troubleshooting steps, whether the root cause is permissions or otherwise.